# How to use an IN statement to select many user's statuses?

Tags: sql, facebook, facebook-fql

My statuses returns many statuses:

```
select message from status where uid = me()
```

Friend's statuses returns many statuses:

```
select message from status where uid in ("639620453")
```

Combining both returns a single status:

```
select message from status where uid in ("36818590","639620453")
```

It looks like a bug with the platform.

Does anyone know an alternate way to select many users' statuses at once?

Comment: Take a look at the [Batch API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5479819/facebook-graph-api-get-all-users-and-their-status) or [fql.multiquery](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/fql.multiquery/)

Answer (score 0):

There does seem to be a bug with this that you should log [here](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs).  A workaround might be to query the stream table.

```
select message, source_id
from stream 
where source_id  in ("36818590","639620453")
```

Comment: Sadly this doesn't work either. Already filed a bug yesterday with FB.

Comment: It worked for me.  Did you make sure you have read_stream permisssions?