# Getting Facebook Status updates with JSon

Tags: jquery, facebook, json, graph, status

For my current university project I need to grab public Facebook status updates with the persons name the message and preferably their image as well to be able to print it in an installation piece. I have looked around a bit but not quite fully getting it. I have looked at the open book source code but that doesn't seem to be all that self explanatory. I understand that I need to use JSon and that using https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=QUERY&type=post&fields=id,name,message,picture will bring up all the Facebook status' with that search term rendering this:

```
{
   "data": [
      {
         "id": "1004039579_403516679661483",
         "name": "Donna Durbin's Photos",
         "message": "DUMPED at 14!!!  I can't imagine what is going through his head poor oh boy Thank God I don't work in a shelter I would be in jail already...Let's HELP this Senior find his FINAL home to rest...plse plse p lse SHARE SHARE this precious pup....thanks",
         "created_time": "2012-03-29T14:18:56+0000"
      },
```

but I'm not really sure what to do with it. I have had a look about but there doesn't really seem to be any tutorials for this. I am a beginner with Javascript only having done a little in the past and mostly having used JQuery, but once pointed down the right path I usually pick it up fairly quickly.

I have seen this: [Facebook Graph API get all users and their status](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5479819/facebook-graph-api-get-all-users-and-their-status) but that doesn't seem to help me with this project and none of the other answered questions seem to really relate to it either.

I would be really grateful of any help people can offer me!

Also does anyone know of a way to get public Facebook status' without the query so the installation is able to print the last status update posted to Facebook, rather than having to base this around a search term.