# Getting friends status updates using graph API

Tags: iphone, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to get friends status updates using graph API in my iPhone app. For this I am using:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/id/statuses?access_token=...
```

But I'm not able to get the response:

```
{
   "data": [

   ]
}
```

Can someone tell me whether is it possible or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this to get the status messages

https://graph.facebook.com/367501354973?access_token=AAAAAAITEghMBAM0UcHwz8aXjdZA0arkzqgG21Qv7xJxuZCDKySWf0aXkgByCLVDJZB0sxyYEn1aAMLVaLSxAvwO3EjBtKc57y5QPQGmPbmLVf1dHMDR

And read message property. That is https://graph.facebook.com/id?access_token=token_here

Btw, visibility is based on privacy settings.

**Alternative**
[Facebook Graph API get all users and their status](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5479819/facebook-graph-api-get-all-users-and-their-status)

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It's possible. The URL that you'd given is in the proper format.

For you it must be because there were no status messages from the user.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Basically the access token which is generated is done so based on permissions assigned. For posts, there is an extended permission which you need to enable called read_stream. Unless and until your access_token is not generated with the mentioned permission, you cannot read posts.

Try generating an access token from here and see

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/?method=GET&path=622206695%3Ffields%3Did%2Cname