# Facebook get user status

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

In my iOS application, I am trying to implement Facebook but am running into a problem. I currently have the user logging in as well as I have implemented the friend picker. I am looking to now have it so when the user taps a friend it will show their status(last post in their feed. e.g.."In NYC on broadway!"). I did a lot of research online but am getting very confused. If someone could point me to good tutorial or could just explain this that would be great. I believe I have to use open graph but other then Facebook's tutorials I can't find any. Are there any tutorials other than on FB?

Comment: What do you mean by "status"? Do you mean the chat status (online, offline, etc)?

Comment: (last post in their feed. e.g.."In NYC on broadway!"

Answer (score 1):

You can access a user's feed by calling `/<userId>/feed` (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me%2Ffeed). Then, look for the first element on `data` array where `"type": "status"`.

Comment: "other then Facebook's tutorials I can't find any" do u know of any others

Comment: I usually search the Graph API documentation (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) for what I'm trying to do.

Comment: and how do i get the <userId>

Comment: Well, if you have a friends list, you probably have their IDs. If you want info about the logged user, you can use "me" instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the answer you're looking for is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5479819/facebook-graph-api-get-all-users-and-their-status), with the exception that you'll basically (I assume) display a list of friends with their profile pic. When clicking on the profile pic the user will see their status? Or you could try to do it all in once (friend name, pic, friend's last status). The facebook developers url they refer to in that post is [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/batch/)